# Multiple HTML page transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to transition between two html pages  in css or javascript. while clicking menu, html page load have transition effect, (Left to right sliding effect) Please advise.

Comment: for this you need to use javascript like `angular` or can see the https://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/ hope that works

Comment: You will have to use `AJAX` to call the page HTML or build a SPA.

Comment: Plz, only javascript and no need to page(div) transition, it is possible to one html between another html transition @ Awsme-thanks

Answer (score 1):

Different transition effect jquery plugin demo link
https://codyhouse.co/demo/animated-transition-effects/fire-extinguisher.html